# Run ClassInitialize multiple times

Tags: c#, visual-studio, selenium, unit-testing, mstest

I am testing a .Net WebApplication using Selenium and MSTest. The application has multiple tiers of user roles and some of the functionality overlaps. I want to create parameterized unit tests for the functionality and want the [ClassInitialize] to run/initialize once per the user role. I want to log **once** into the web application(target is to log into the webapp in the [ClassInitialize]) and then run the unittest. And when the unittests against that user roles are finished, the [ClassInitialize] should run again and log into different user role.

I tried using [Datasource] with the[ClassInitialize] and obviously it doesn't work.

Any idea how I can achieve this architecture?

Comment: You can take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14673329/7225096

Answer (score 0):

I’m afraid not. The [ClassInitialize] just runs once during the test project running.

Please refer here: [Test lifecycle attributes](https://www.meziantou.net/mstest-v2-test-lifecycle-attributes.htm)

From that blog, the [TestInitialize] will be called before running each [TestMethod].

But the [DataSource]  does not support [TestInitialize], we couldn’t get values from this
data source. The “testcontext.dataRow” would be null.

So we could use [TestMethod] with [DataSource]. It will automatically run with different

user roles which is from your database. And you could create a test method to call other

test methods for your different users.

The sample with csv database:

```
[TestClass]
    public class UnitTest1
    {
        [TestMethod]
        [DataSource("Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.DataSource.CSV", @"C:\Users\Administrator\source\repos\UnitTestProject2\UnitTestProject2\data.csv", "data#csv", DataAccessMethod.Sequential)]
        public void TestMethod1()
        {
            string va = TestContext.DataRow["Num1"].ToString();
            switch (va)
            {
                case "1": TEST1(); break;
                case "4": TEST2(); break;
            }
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void TEST1()
        { 
            //Todo
         }

        [TestMethod]
        public void TEST2()
        {
            //Todo
        }

        private TestContext testContextInstance;
        public TestContext TestContext
        {
            get { return testContextInstance; }
            set { testContextInstance = value; }
        }
    }
```